# How can I parse multiple tables into one dataframe?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have applied beautiful soup prettifier and got this:

```
<div class="vbr_building_result">
             <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
               <td class="label">
                District:
               </td>
               <td>
                Point Grey
               </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
               <td class="label" valign="top">
                Owner:
               </td>
               <td>
                Dunsmuir, John Jr.
               </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
               <td class="label" valign="top">
                Builder:
               </td>
               <td>
                Barwick, J. W.
               </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
               <td class="label" valign="top">
```

So there are a lot of small tables that start with div class="var_building_result"
Can I get all of these tables into one dataframe with columns "District", "Owner", "Builder"?
I tried 
`item.find('div', {'class': 'vbr_building_result'}).find(<tr>)`, but that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, you appear to be trying to get data from a scraped table into a python pandas dataframe.

What you can do in pandas is use [read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html), which will convert your data from html into a dataframe (use something like `soup.find_all('table')` and loop over your results to concatenate/append your python tables).

Comment: Thank you! That almost worked but how can I loop over tables? I did `table_div = soup.find('div' , {'class': 'vbr_building_result'})` and then `table = table_div.find('table')` `pd.read_html(table.prettify(),skiprows=2, flavor='bs4')` but I only got the first table this way

Comment: `soup.find` returns the first instance of the object .... `soup.find_all` will return a list-like with all instances of the object.